# How do popular reducing agents react on compounds that have ester, carbonyl, and unsaturated functionalities?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

Suppose we have a chemical compound like ethyl 4-oxo-2-cyclopentene-1-carboxylate

[image: Ethyl 4-oxo-2-cyclopentene-1-carboxylate]

It is $\ce{-COOC2H5}$ bonded to a five-membered carbon ring with one double bond and the ring has another carbonyl group.

Suppose this compound is made to react with these *reducing agents*:

1. $\ce{NaBH4}$
2. $\ce{LiAlH4}$ and $\ce{H+}$
3. $\ce{BH3}$, $\ce{THF}$, and $\ce{H+}$
4. $\ce{H2/Pt}$
5. $\ce{H2/Pd-C}$

Then what will be the product in each cases?

I know some of the reducing agents and I want to know their reactions with a compound which is unsaturated and has an ester functionality $\ce{-COOR}$ and a carbonyl group $\ce{R2C=O}$ bonded to it.
I cannot try to understand it due to my limited knowledge in chemical mechanisms.